# Swift: how to perform a task n-1 times where n is the length of an array?

Tags: swift

I came to this:

```
for x in 1...(myArray.count - 1) { task() }
```

which is very ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you want to collect the results from running `task()`, or is it something that is only there to mutate state elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be a little careful, as if the array is empty, this will crash:

```
let a: [Int] = []
let range = 0..<a.count-1
// fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start
```

Strides don’t have this problem (since `Strideable` things must be `Comparable`) so you could do:

```
for _ in stride(from: 0, to: a.count - 1, by: 1) {
    // will only execute if a.count > 2
    print("blah")
}
```

Alternatively, if you guard it, you can use `dropFirst`:

```
for _ in (a.isEmpty ? [] : dropFirst(a))  {
    print("blah")
}
```

I would strongly advise *against* trying to make this look neater by creating a pseudo-for-loop that runs one less than the count times.  There’s a reason that there’s no `forEach` or `repeat` functions in Swift. These kind of loops seem nice at first but there are lots of bugs that arise from them (for example, `return` or `continue` don’t work the way you might expect, also it’s generally considered bad practice to use a higher-order function to do external mutation – whereas a regular `for` loop is a suggestion that mutation/side-effects are likely).

The neatest extension-type solution would probably be to extend `Array` to do a safe drop-first:

```
extension Array {
    // version of dropFirst that returns empty array for both
    // empty and single-element array
    func safeDropFirst() -> ArraySlice<T> {
        return self.isEmpty ? [] : dropFirst(self)
    }
}

for _ in myArray.safeDropFirst() {
    doThing()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not much better, but:

```
for _ in 1..<myArray.count { task() }
```

But this will crash if `myArray` is empty (thanks, [Airspeed Velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3925941/airspeed-velocity)).

If you happen to need that a lot for some reason, you can provide your own “loop abstraction” and take care of that issue too:

```
func repeatArray<T>(arr: [T], @noescape f: () -> Void) {
    if !arr.isEmpty {
        for _ in 1..<arr.count {
            f()
        }
    }
}

repeatArray(myArray) {
    task()
}
```

Comment: `for _ in 1..<myArray.count { task() }` will crash your program if the array is ever empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with Swift 2:

```
for x in myArray where x != myArray.first { task() }
```